# Parse setApplicationId:... exception on iPad 1 running Xcode 6

Tags: parse-platform

My iOS app was working fine yesterday. I have made no changes to Parse code.

Last night, I upgraded Xcode to 6 and now when running on my iPad 1 (device), the app crashes immediately in [Parse setAppplication...]
==> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x65d4048d)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [Parse setApplicationId:@"*******" clientKey:@"*******"];
```

It works fine if I run with my iPhone 4 (device).

fyi:
- Xcode Deployment Target = 5.1 (so that I can support iPad 1).
- Base SDK latest iOS (iOS 8.0)

Comment: The app and client key are hidden (and correct in my code)... works fine on iPhone 4.

Comment: I just remembered that I also recently updated my Parse SDK to latest (1.4.1), and just realized that Parse has not supported iOS 5.1 since 1.2.21. So, I guess I need to move back to Parse 1.2.21 if I want to continue to support iPad 1 (iOS 5.1).  Regardless, that exception seems like a strange way for Parse to fail.